# Python add values in one list according to names in another list

Tags: python, list

So, I've got 2 lists 
`veg_type = [Urban,Urban,Forest,OpenForest,Arboretum]`
`veg_density = [0.5,0.6,0.1,0,0.9]`
I want to add up the veg_density corresponding to the veg_type. So that means that `Urban = 1.1 (This is 0.5+0.6)`
`Forest = 0.1`
`OpenForest = 0`
`Arboretum = 0.9`
The index of veg_density and veg_type have the same values. That means that is Urban appears at position 0, its corresponding veg_density is also in position 0.
Also , I cannot assume that the elements in veg_type is confined to the above examples .
How do I go about solving this ?

Comment: Think "dictionary".

Comment: why not consider pandas

Answer (score 4):

Using dictionaries (key-to-value maps) will allow you to solve your problem:

```
veg_type = ["Urban", "Urban", "Forest", "OpenForest", "Arboretum"]
veg_density = [0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0, 0.9]

type_density = {} #Creates a new dictionary

if len(veg_type) == len(veg_density): #pointed out by @lalengua -- veg_type and veg_density need to have the same length
    for i in range(len(veg_type)):
        if veg_type[i] not in type_density: #If the veg_type isn't in the dictionary, add it
            type_density[veg_type[i]] = 0

        type_density[veg_type[i]] += veg_density[i]
```

This produces:

```
{'Urban': 1.1, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Arboretum': 0.9}
```

With it's values being accessed like so:

```
type_density['Urban'] = #some value
some_variable = type_density['Forest'] #double quotes can be used as well
```

A few things about dictionaries:

- Dictionaries have *keys* which correspond to certain values
- Keys are unique in a dictionary -- redefining a key will overwrite it's value
- Keys can be strings, numbers or objects -- anything that can be hashed
- Keys need to be in the dictionary in order to apply operations to them
- To predefine a dictionary (rather than having it empty), use the following: `name = {key1 : value1, key2 : value2, key3 : value3, keyN : valueN}`

You can read more about `dict`ionary objects [at the offical python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dictionaries#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: This is the clearest answer and code, nothing to import and simpler than that `oneliner` snobism, just be shure `veg_type` and `veg_density` have same size or it will brake.

Comment: You can use dict.get instead of `if veg_type[i] not in type_density`

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
print({k:sum([veg_density[i] for i,val in enumerate(veg_type) if val == k]) for k,v in veg_type})
```

Output:

```
{'Urban': 1.1, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Arboretum': 0.9}
```

To explain:

- make a dictionary with keys of `veg_type`, using `fromkeys`
- do a dictionary comprehension for summing the values using `sum`, iterating trough indexes and values of `veg_type` and get the values that are the key `k` then get index and get `veg_density` value with that index

Or Use `pandas`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(veg_type,veg_density)))
print(df.groupby(0)[1].sum().to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'Arboretum': 0.90000000000000002, 'Forest': 0.10000000000000001, 'OpenForest': 0.0, 'Urban': 1.1000000000000001}
```

If Care about decimals:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(veg_type,veg_density)))
print({k:float("%.2f"%v) for k,v in df.groupby(0)[1].sum().to_dict().items()})
```

Output:

```
{'Arboretum': 0.9, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0.0, 'Urban': 1.1}
```

To Explain:

- create a data frame using `pandas` with a list value of a `list(zip(..))` for `veg_type` and `veg_density`
- then do pandas `groupby` for removing duplicates in columns `0`, then pushed down, that get the sum of columns `1` with the column 0 having the value in the same row

Related:

> [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Note:

> Pandas is a library that has to be installed, not a default package

Comment: Your two liner can be `{vt: sum([veg_density[i] for i, tvt in enumerate(veg_type) if tvt == vt]) for vt in veg_type}`. You don't need to create `d`.

Comment: @slider That's right forgot, to addict to dictionaries :-)

Comment: @slider Done it

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> veg_type = ['Urban','Urban','Forest','OpenForest','Arboretum']
>>> veg_density = [0.5,0.6,0.1,0,0.9]
>>> sums = defaultdict(int)
>>> for name,value in zip(veg_type,veg_density):
...     sums[name] += value
...
>>> sums
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Urban': 1.1, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Arboretum': 0.9})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
veg_type = ["Urban", "Urban", "Forest", "OpenForest", "Arboretum"]
veg_density = [0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0, 0.9]

duos = zip(veg_type, veg_density)
result = {}   #or dict.fromkeys(set(veg_type), 0)
for i in set(veg_type):
    result[i] = sum([d for t, d in duos if t==i])
```

output:

{'Arboretum': 0.9, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Urban': 1.1}

Version in a line:

```
veg_type = ["Urban", "Urban", "Forest", "OpenForest", "Arboretum"]
veg_density = [0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0, 0.9]

{ e:sum([d for t, d in zip(veg_type, veg_density) if t==e]) for e in set(veg_type)}
```

output:

{'Arboretum': 0.9, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Urban': 1.1}

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` the two lists together and then use `groupby` to populate your `dictionary`. `itemgetter` can be replaced with `lambda x: x[0]`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

z = zip(veg_type, veg_density)
d = {}
for k, g in groupby(z, key=itemgetter(0)):
    d[k] = sum([i[1] for i in g])
# {'Urban': 1.1, 'Forest': 0.1, 'OpenForest': 0, 'Arboretuem': 0.9}
```